# How to grant an app administrator permissions with adb?

Tags: android, windows, mobile, permissions, adb

Yea I just want a specific app on my samsung A10 to be undeletable.
if it's not possible by using adb I would like to hear some other possible ways to do that.

:D

Answer (score 0):

hello There are quite a few apps in the Market which will lock certain apps behind a password, a search in the Market for "applock" should find most of them.